# Running repeating javascript fetch requests is filling up browser memory quickly. Is there a way to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm building a webpage that displays a live stream of events containing images. To do this, I've decided to try using javascript running client side with the code below to fetch data from my API endpoint every 1 second (and then update the html accordingly). I've noticed that the result of each fetch request is being persisted in memory and this will quickly fill up the browsers memory, especially if run for a few hours or entire day as planned.

I've searched the internet and found that I can set the created objects as null to mark them as safe to clear for the garbage collector but I'm new to javascript and I'm not sure where/what to actually set equal to null. Do you know what I should be setting to null in the code below?

If there's any other solution, guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Code:
EDIT: Removed setTimeout(1) - still get the same behaviour outlined above

```js
let myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("xxxx", "xxxxxx");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");

let raw = "{x:x}";

let requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

function printResult(result){
    console.log(result);
}

function getLatestRecords(){
    fetch("https://xxxx.xxxx.com", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => printResult(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

    //setTimeout(1)
}

let interval = setInterval(
    function() {
        getLatestRecords()
    },
    1000
);
```

Looks like data objects are being created for each fetch:

[image: fetch objects created]

Comment: It might be because you are console logging them. Every time you console log an object it creates a copy of that object on the console.

Comment: Hi Adrian. Thanks, I just tried without console logging them and still looks like memory is getting filled up

Comment: What is that `setTimeout(1)`?

Comment: It looks like your dev tools are keeping around a copy of each fetch, so that's probably where the leak is. Unless you're doing something else that's not posted in your code, nothing should be causing a memory leak.

Comment: The `setTimeout(1)` doesn't look right, that will leak handles I think.

Comment: @Jacob the setTimeout(1) should timeout the function if it takes longer than 1 second (before the next function call is made)

Comment: Did you redefine `setTimeout`? That's not normally what it does.

Comment: The syntax for `setTimeout` is `setTimeout(callbackFunction, timeInMs)` so that looks wrong to start with.

Comment: @Jacob no - I'm probably mistaken - I read that's what it does - I removed it now but still get the same behaviour with regards to the memory issue

Comment: If you want a request timeout, to cancel the request if it takes too long, then you can't do that in `fetch()` as far as I know.  It's possible with `XMLHttpRequest` but not as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks @RobinBalmforth - I'll look into XMLHttpRequest to figure out how to timeout a request

Comment: Removing the setTimeout has actually changed the behaviour - the GC is now running properly, no idea how that affected it but its working fine now. Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if this relates to your memory leak, but you are using `setTimeout` in a bizarre fashion. [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) is for scheduling a callback to be invoked after a certain number of milliseconds; `setTimeout(1)` is undefined behavior.

Since your intent is to make your fetch request be cancelled after 1 second, you'll want to do this instead:

```
function getLatestRecords(){
    var controller = new AbortController();
    setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 1000);
    return fetch("https://xxxx.xxxx.com", { ...requestOptions, signal: controller.signal })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => printResult(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

Comment: Today I Learned about `AbortController`! Thanks @Jacob

Comment: Thank you for this Jacob! Removing the setTimeout the way I was using it fixed the problem and now the GC is working as expected. I'll def use this method to timeout the requests going forward, thanks.

Comment: Glad it was that simple! Who'd have thought that `setTimeout(1)` would cause a memory leak? Weird.

Comment: Yeah crazy - weird behaviour even though I was using it incorrectly.